# Raspberry Pi Pico: receiving on multiple UARTs

Tags: microcontroller, uart, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

**Expected behavior:**

In hardware I connect UART of a number `0/1` to the correct pin numbers `TX/RX` and get it based on that connection

**Actual behavior:**

In hardware I connect UART of a number `0/1` to the correct pin numbers `TX/RX` and got it on all of the related UARTs `0/1`.

I have this array of UARTs where I can split them like USB ports, and when I receive an input I get it from different indices.

To me it's a bit strange but it gets on all `UART0` at once even though I'm connecting a certain one only, or the same on all `UART1`.

```py
ports = [
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1)),
    UART(1, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5)),
    UART(1, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(8), rx=Pin(9)),
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(12), rx=Pin(13)),
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(16), rx=Pin(17))
]
```

The code:

```py
from machine import UART, Pin
from time import time
import re

ports = [
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(0), rx=Pin(1)),
    UART(1, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5)),
    UART(1, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(8), rx=Pin(9)),
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(12), rx=Pin(13)),
    UART(0, 115200, timeout=0, tx=Pin(16), rx=Pin(17))
]

def read_ports():
    """Returns a list of ports with indecies that are receiving data"""
    port_list = []
    for i,port in enumerate(ports):
        if port.any() > 0:
            port_list.append({
                "port": port, "index": i
            })
    return port_list

request = [
    bytes(),
    bytes(),
    bytes(),
    bytes(),
    bytes()
]

while True:
    # Available Ports
    active_ports = read_ports()
    
    if len(active_ports) == 0:
        continue
    
    for uart in active_ports:
        index, port = uart["index"], uart["port"]
        byte = port.read(1)
        
        if byte == b'' or None or not byte:
            continue
        
        print("(index %d) (length %d) byte" % (index, len(request[index])), byte)

        request[index] += byte
```

If I have UART0 connected all UART0s get the bytes at random.

I just don't get it; why? And how to solve it?

And if it's normal behavior  what is the point of having all of these UART ports if I can't use one when I need many?

Answer (score 2):

The Pi Pico only has two UARTs.  Each UART can be assigned to one of several pairs of I/O pins.

What happens when you assign UART0 to all the UART0 pins at once is unspecified, but probably not useful.

Comment: I really wish that there is a way to identify and specify each pin for what and use it like a custom usb connector.

Answer (score 0):

daisy chain picos through UART connections
https://github.com/JMartinUSN/Pi-PICO/commit/3ae8d4de11fbb7d85cc71dfa16a7fd1aa5ede5a8

Comment: Joel Martin - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However (a) As far as I understand the OP, they are trying to use multiple connections to UARTs 0 & 1 simultaneously. How does your proposal to "daisy chain picos through UART connections" solve that problem? If the UARTs are used to daisy chain Picos, then those UARTs aren't available to receive data from any other sources, which seems to be what the OP is trying to do. Please can you [edit] this answer to explain how it applies to the OP's question?

Comment: (continued) (b) Since you've linked to your own GitHub repo, please follow the [promotion rule](/help/promotion) and make a clear disclosure in the answer that you are linking to *your* code. (c) As it says in that rule: "*Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself*" so please add much more detail in the answer. TY (FYI the main site rules are in the [tour] & [help].)